# Binding data to textbox, making it uneditable

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, html

I have a textbox which I would like bound with data from the logged in user, so that the user can't edit it. Would this need to be a label, or is there another way?

```
<p>Practice: &nbsp;
   <input class="form-control" type="text" value="6666666 - Siya's Awesome world" readonly="readonly" id="txtName" />                           
</p>
```

Ps. I don't want the values entered as I did above. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Add the code you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Use input like this :

```
<input readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled" class="text-box single-line readonly" id="field-id" name="field-name" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Rai Vu. But it's the code-behind that I'm struggling with.

Comment: what's it in code-behind that you are struggling with??